# ccscene arc and autorelease

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to construct a number of scenes in my GameManager singleton init.

The scene is created via

```
   - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {        // 'mainScene' is an autorelease object.
        mainScene = [CCScene node];  
...  
    }
```

GameManger holds a strong reference to mainScene:

```
@interface GameManager : NSObject
{
    CCScene* mainScene;
}
```

But if I try to push the scene later with

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:mainScene];
```

I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS

If I create and immediately push then everything works.  Shouldn't the default __strong reference keep the object allocated?

Thanks in advance for any help....

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out ... [CCScene node] is a convenience factory method that does:
[[[self alloc] init] autorelease];

but since I am using arc...I dont want that - I want

```
mainScene = [[CCScene alloc]init];
```

instead of

```
mainScene = [CCScene node];
```

Comment: Neither makes any difference when you're using ARC. [CCScene node] and [[CCScene alloc] init] will work identically with ARC (although the low-level technical details reveal slightly different memory management routines). Be sure that you're not falling into the trap of pushing the currently running scene, that will crash.

Comment: I was definitely not pushing a running scene - and verified calling [[[CCScene alloc]init] autorelease]; crashes and [[CCScene alloc]init] does not....